# ARIMA model on sales data

Tags: time-series, arima

I have a 'theory' question based on the ARIMA model. I have **daily** sales data for about 3 years, so I could apply ARIMA to the data. However, the data contains categorical variables. My data structure is as follows:

```
Business_Day    Location    Product_Type    Sales_Value
01/01/2019  Pretoria    Steel   2345.50
01/01/2019  Pretoria    Metal   5789.75
01/01/2019  Johannesburg    Steel   325.77
01/01/2019  Johannesburg    Metal   150
02/01/2019  Pretoria    Steel   4587.22
...
```

I can apply the ARIMA model to the different series's (by splitting on categorical variables). If i look at each of the individual (for each of the categorical variables) series's I obtain different models paramters (P,d,Q) to use for each of the series's.

So, basically my questions are this:

Because I get different series results to use, should I then create a model for each of different categorical variables (currently 9 different locations and 5 different product types)? Can you create a 'Generalized' model that takes each of the individual models into consideration?

Comment: Could you clarify the sense in which the data "contain" categorical variables, what it means to "split" on them, and what the form of the "generalized result" might take?  What would be the objective of this exercise?

Comment: I have updated the question with the data structure. The categorical variables are `Location` and `Product Type`. What I mean about "split" is to create a series for each of the variables (series for Location Pretoria and series for Johannesburg) and create a model for each one. The objective is to do Predictions/Forecasting on this Time Series and if the ARIMA model can be used for this.

Comment: I would create 45 individual daily models using day-of-the-week, month-of-the-year, day-of-the-month,pre and post holiday effects, level shifts, trend changes and ARIMA structure. I would examine them for "similarity" with an eye to possibly reducing the # of models.

Comment: If you think there are dependencies between regional sales and/or between sales of different products, then it is better to use VAR. In fact, it is highly likely that there is going to be correlation between sales across regions at least for same product. So it would be better to use VAR.